# FTP server configuration

Tags: chroot, ftp

I am configuring VsFTPd 2.2.2 server on Debian 5.0.
I want user after login can see and edit just two dirs:

```
/home/user/
/var/www/project1/
/var/www/project2/
```

Possible solutions

1. I can Chroot user just in one of this directories. 
   But I dont want to use symlinks or "mount --bind" because I have a lot of users and I dont want to have very big fstab file. Also the user should see exactly "/var/www/project1/" but not /home/user/var-www-project1/.
2. I can set local_root=/. 
   In this case user will see all dirs(bin   dev   etc   lib    lost+found  mnt  proc  sbin     sent  sys  usr boot  emul  home  lib64  media       opt  root  selinux  srv   tmp  var). It also does not satisfy me  :(

Answer (score 2):

[Vsftp config](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/01/ftp-server.html)

Comment: In fact I want option:
deny_file=NOT_/home/user,NOT_/var/project1,NOT_/var/project2

Answer (score 2):

```
MAN vsftpd hide_file
```

This option can be used to set a pattern for filenames (and directory names etc.) which should be hidden from directory listings. Despite being hidden, the files / directories etc.. are fully accessible to clients who know what names to actually use. Items will be hidden if their names contain the string given by hide_file, or if they match the regular expression specified by hide_file. Note that vsftpd's regular expression matching code is a simple implementation which is a subset of full regular expression functionality.

See deny_file for details of exactly what regex syntax is supported.

Example: `hide_file={*.mp3,.hidden,hide*,h?}`

Comment: I've already read it. Unfortunatelly I dont want to list all dirs that I want to deny/hide.

Comment: i also trying in my test server wait for same time i'll test and then i'll let you know!!

Answer (score 0):

I also think there's no way to do that, appart using the hide_file.

*(The alternative i tried which is not one because i won't work was:
 1. Creating a new dir which serves as a container
 2. Putting in that new dir one symbolic link for each directory i want to allow accces to
 3. Jailing the user in that new dir
=> But it won't work because of the jail... : The user just can't get out of the new dir, so he can't use the symbolic links...)*